# Alert error when a city name is spelled wrong in a weather app

Tags: javascript

What will be the easiest way to add an alert statement when the user types a wrong name or number?

```js
let weather = {
  fetchWeather: function(city) {
    fetch(
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
        city + "&units=metric&appid=fa73f7986fd7a4a71b32273d81cd9fce"
      )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.displayWeather(data));
  },
  displayWeather: function(data) {
    const { name } = data;
    const { icon , description } = data.weather[0];
    const { temp , humidity } = data.main;
    const { speed } = data.wind;

    document.querySelector(".city").innerHTML = "Weather in " + name;
    document.querySelector(".icon").src = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + ".png";
    document.querySelector(".description").innerHTML = description;
    document.querySelector(".temp").innerHTML = temp + " °C";
    document.querySelector(".humidity").innerHTML = "Humidity : " + humidity + " %";
    document.querySelector(".wind").innerHTML = "Wind Speed : " + speed + " km/h";
  },

  search: function() {
    this.fetchWeather(document.querySelector(".search_bar").value);
  }
}


document.querySelector(".search").addEventListener("click", function() {
  weather.search();

})
```

Comment: I made a snippet. Please add HTML to make a [mcve]

Comment: Did you write the code or is this copy pasted from somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Just check return value of API call. If wrong city return value is:

```
{"cod":"404","message":"city not found"}
```

Then modify your code to something like this:

```
function(city) {
     fetch(
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
        city + "&units=metric&appid=xxx"
      )
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
     if(data.cod && data.cod === "404") {
         alert("City not found");
     } else {
         displayWeatherData(data);
     }
  });
}
```

Note: dont publish API keys.

Comment: Thanks for the code its working and from next time I'll make sure not to publish the key thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `if` statement in your `displayWeather` function to create an alert if there is no data :

```
displayWeather: function(data) {
  if (!data) {
    alert("Message here");
    return;
  }
  const { name } = data;
  [...]
```